# How do I overlay files on top of a public git repo?

Tags: git

I have some code that I need to maintain in a private git repo, but compiles and runs as part of a framework that is in an open source git repo. I prefer to keep only the files I added/modified (I have both) in my private repo. I was hoping there was a way to do something like...

- Clone public repo
- Checkout specific tag
- Clone my repo (overwrite public repo if I have a modified version, and add my new files)

Git does not seem to have an option to merge without a hard sync, i.e., make destination look exactly like the source.

Appreciate any pointers! Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean? That can easily be done with `git checkout whatever-revision-or-tag -- .` (make my tree look like that one, do not mess with history).

Comment: I wonder what you would like to achieve. For you, the open source project/framework is an `upstream`. You keep changes on files on a _downstream_ branch and you should be able to pull from your upstream branch to get the updates from the opensource project while keeping your stuff _private_. What complexity do you find there?

Comment: @eftshift0 thanks for responding. You are right if the requirement was to keep changes in a branch. However, I'd like to keep my changes (new/modified files) in my private repo, and I do _not_ want to keep the master branch code there. I want the repo to have only the changed files, and when I build it, I'd like to pull the public repo, switch to the right tag, then _overlay_ my changes on top, and then build. Apologies if I am missing something very basic. :-(

Comment: It sounds like you have a misunderstanding of _concepts_. A branch is nothing more than a glorified pointer to a revision (and that git automatically takes care for us on some opeeations like moving when xommitting if we are on a local branch) and repos hold branches.... and you can hold private stuff private as long as you wantm _Nothing_ forces you to put stuff in a public repo to be able to pull stuff from another repo. Say, I can have a local (and private) repo having a **remote** point to a public open source project. My local branch can be called main... or master... or bonkers....

Comment: ... it doesn't matter, cause no one but _I_ will see/use it. Then I can fetch and pull stuff into my private branches. Isn't that what you *should* be trying to achieve? Or how else do you expect to get changes from upstream? *Replacing* full files with what you have in your branch? That's an easy no-go under normal circumstances.

Comment: Okay, I am clearly not able to explain the issue, and that's my bad. Yes, I do understand git concepts, and no I don't want to replace full files. Let me try this - I have 2 options: 1) clone a specific tag from the public repo, add my files (none conflict with public, only adds) and then keep all the code (mine and public) in my private repo. Or, 2) maintain onl my files, write up some scripts that clone public repo, switch to right tag, add in my files, compile. I do _not_ want #1 since one wouldn't trivially know which files I added. I could do #2, but I am asking if there is any other way.

Comment: @schugcove I was about to say basically 2) that you just wrote up. I don't think what you are looking for already exists, so it would have to be on you to script it as part of your build procedure.

Comment: Now, I disagree with one of your points: if you base you branch on the upstream and keep their files in your repo, you can still do `git diff --stat their-tag my-HEAD` to see which files you've added or changed. So while I see what you're trying to achieve, I'm not convinced it's necessary to maintain the information you want.

Comment: @joanis thank you for the information and for following my poorly worded request. And thanks also for the git diff command, I did not know about that.